# Replace single quote in a string not working

Tags: php, string, replace

I'm having trouble replacing a single quote in a string, the purpose is to create part of an URL

For example : If I type in "Villeneuve d'ascq" I would want to have :

`Villeneuve+d%27ascq", %27` being the ascii equivalent of `(')`

I tried using `str_replace("'", ord("'"), string_name)` but it doesn't seem to work

Any help would be appreciated and feel free to ask for any more details

Comment: Is there something wrong with [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode)?

Comment: Did you replaced all the characters with `str_replace`? Don't tell me you are live with that code.

Comment: http://php.net/urlencode does the job.

Comment: I'll try using urlencode when possible and get back to you, thanks

Comment: You can also try to escape it by doing "\'"

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
echo '<a href="test.com', urlencode(."Villeneuve d'ascq".), '">test</a>';
```

You can also check this at : 
[PHP MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: Sorry but this is not a question that needs an answer. These types of questions should be marked as duplicate. Also it was resolved in a manner that it won't help any future readers.